# Как выбрать последние сообщения?

Tags: php, sql

Есть вот такая таблица :

`id | id_from | id_for | message | message_status`

И есть такой запрос:

```
          SELECT
            m.message AS message,
            fu.username AS username,
            fu.img AS img,
            fu.id as id,
            m.message_status as status,
            m.id as idm
          FROM
            users AS fu
          LEFT JOIN
            user_message AS m
          ON
            m.id_for = fu.id
          WHERE
            m.id_from = "'.$_SESSION['id'].'"
            order by idm desc
```

Сейчас он выбирает первое сообщение в чате между пользователями, а мне нужно последнее. Т.е message где id больше предыдущих сообщений
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно ли я понимаю, что вам нужна информация об одном сообщении и соответствующему ему пользователю? Вам обязательно решить задачу одним запросом? Там будет один основной и 3 коррелированных запроса или JOIN. Это не всегда самый продуктивный путь - уложить все в один запрос. Выполните два запроса - это тоже не так много. Первым запросом извлеките всю информацию об адресатах

```
SELECT
  message AS message,
  id_for AS id_for,
  message_status as status,
  id as idm
FROM
  user_message
WHERE
  id_from = "'.$_SESSION['id'].'"
ORDER BY
  m.id DESC
```

В цикле вы помещает всю информацию об ответах в массива $answers, плюс дополнительно готовите массив $id_for с идентификаторами пользователей. Далее выполняете запрос

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  user
WHERE
  id IN ( ".implode(",", $id_for)." )
```

Помещаете информацию обо всех пользователей в ассоциативный массив $users, в котором ключем служит идентификатор пользователя. Затем в цикле формируете таблицу ответов $answers, когда нужно получить информацию о пользователе обращаетесь к массиву $users

```
$users[$answers['id_for']]
```

Comment: Сейчас уже выводит последнее сообщение, но появилась новая проблема, дублирует пользователей (я загрузил картинку примера)

Comment: В варианте, который приведен в этом ответе, я предлагаю вам отказаться от первоначального запроса и воспользоваться двумя запросами.

Comment: В целом мне нужно из базы достать, фото, имя, id, последнее сообщение и статус(прочитанное ли сообщение) чтобы все это разместить в блоке, как на примере. И вроде бы все как бы работает, осталось убрать дубли. Ваш вариант легче в восприятии, но я не знаю что дальше с этим делать, как пустить все это дело в цикл и вытащить что требуется?

Comment: Переформулировал.

Comment: Буду разбираться, спасибо! Но почему ваш вариант лучше изначального, в конце концов получится одно и тоже?

Comment: Есть два довода. JOIN - не бесплатен, чтобы его создать нужно объединить две таблицы в одну большую, количество элементов в которой равно произведению записей этих таблиц. Т.е. если у вас в одной таблице 100 записей и в другой 100, в промежуточной будет 10 000. В случае LEFT JOIN это немного не так, плюс есть оптимизации. Однако, факт есть факт, чем больше таблицы, тем дороже JOIN. В случае двух запросов - проблемы нет - в большинстве случаев они будут дешевле.

Comment: Второй довод: SQL создавался в 70-х, когда машины были дорогими, а зарплата людей по сравнению с их стоимостью ничего не стоила. Сейчас ситуация другая - машины дешевы, время программиста - дорого. Вы провозитесь с SQL-запросом сутки или двое, вместо того, чтобы запилить цикл понятный и вам и тем, кто придет после вас. Большие простыни SQL сейчас экономически не обоснованы - дорого их создавать и поддерживать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37344/discussion-between---and-cheops).

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете сделать одним из двух способов:

1. ... `ORDER BY m.id desc LIMIT 1`; -- дописать в конец запроса
2. Изменить выборку по id сообщения вот так: `SELECT MAX(m.id) ....`

В обоих случаях нужно будет убрать группировку по username, потому что она теряет смысл.

Comment: Забавно получилось, проверил в консоле, id выводятся по убыванию в отдельной колонке, но сообщения все равно выводит не последние..

Comment: поставил group by message, но теперь повторяются пользователи